# Get value from NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have an `NSTextField` and I need to get the field's value into a variable. What's the appropriate method?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

For an `NSString` you would use:

```
NSString *myString = [theTextField stringValue];
```

For an `int` you would use:

```
int myInt = [theTextField intValue];
```

There are many other methods for getting the value from a control. Have a look at the `NSControl` reference for more info, under the ["Getting and Setting the Control’s Value" section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000073-SW8).

Here's a list:

- `doubleValue`
- `floatValue`
- `intValue`
- `integerValue`
- `objectValue`
- `stringValue`
- `attributedStringValue`

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3.x Version:

```
myField.stringValue
```

Answer (score 3):

`[myField stringValue]`

`NSTextField` inherits from `NSControl`, and `NSControl` defines the `stringValue`/`setStringvalue:` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

Say you have an object (`MyObject`) that wants to be be notified when someone types into a `NSTextField`. In the .h file, `MyObject` should declare it conforms to `NSTextFieldDelegate`, as in...

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject <NSTextFieldDelegate>
```

Then you set MyObject as the delegate of the `NSTextField`

`[myTextField setDelegate:myObject]`

Now, you can find out when something happens in the textfield by implementing methods in MyObject like:

```
-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
-(void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
```